# htaccess: migrating from server root directory to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, relative-path

So far my application ran in server's root directory so every link in app's scripts was **relative** (i.e. /media/style.css). Application was so far accessible in http://jazyky.cz

Now **I moved my app to dev server's subdirectory** `/home/david/public_html/jazyky` so app URL is now http://dev.company.cz/~david/jazyky and WWW folder (accessible from outside) is accessible through http://dev.company.cz/~david/jazyky/htdocs.

Inside this `htdocs` directory there is folder `media` into which all the application links point to.

I'm just terribly unqualified with .htaccess so I'm asking anyone for an advice.

**How should I adjust my .htaccess file** (situaded inside `htdocs` folder) **so that all links inside application were mapped correctly?**

My current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is you already have links as `/media/style.css` on your HTML page and `media` folder is directly under `htdocs` then links should work find as is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For example, in my script I have this link: `/media/css/screen.student.css?ver=` and if I try to reach it through clickable firefox link, it tries to access URL: `http://dev.company.cz/media/css/screen.student.css?ver=7` instead of `http://dev.company.cz/~david/jazyky/htdocs/media/css/screen.student.css?ver=7`

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule on top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+media/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ ~david/jazyky/htdocs/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This rule looks pretty advanced. Unfortunately it does not work even though it should. I solved my problem by creating virtual host so no worries. Thank you anyway!